# Pre-fill fields when creating an entry in CP

Tags: entries, redactor, fieldtypes

I am using redactor plugin for my field type and I want to use global values of the same field type to be used as pre-fill value when creating a new entry.

Use case:

Each year there is an edition of a program with more or less the same text (multiple fields), but minor adjustments can occur.

So by creating a new edition (entry) in the control panel, I want to already pre-fill the standard values of the fields (configured as a global)
Then I can update, if necessary, some text for this new edition and save it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This functionality could be created in a plugin or module, but why wouldn't you **duplicate** the entry and change the fields you need to change?